# For loop function not returning the correct output

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program to see how many times a 3-digit substring shows up in a string. For example, the substring "122" would show up in the string "122122" 2 times. However, whenever I run it, it returns 0, even if the substring does actually show up. Can you tell me what's wrong with my function?

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range (len(string)): 
        if string[i:i+3] == sub_string:
           count+=1
```

Comment: No `return` in your function?

Comment: It doesn't return 0, it returns `None`.  You gotta `return count` at the end!

Comment: You can also just use the built-in `count` function.  Try `"122122".count("122")`!

Answer (score 1):

Using @Samwise's comment as a suggestion:

```py
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    return string.count(sub_string)
```

Although, since that's a one-liner, if you only need to run this function once, you may not even want to break it off into its own function. So just use `string.count(sub_string)` where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    return string.count(sub_string)
```